# Laravel handles user's concurrent requests sequentially

Tags: laravel, session, redis

Laravel handles user's concurrent requests sequentially. How to handle requests concurrently? It seems that session (held in Redis store) blocks concurrent requests but maybe it's not the reason. Where the problem?

Vue sends requests...

```
async manageData() {
   // array of chart's properties
   const charts = await axios.post('/report/chart_data', {id: this.id);
   // concurrent requests with variable 'charts'
   const result = await Promise.all(
      charts.map((chart, key) => axios.post('/report/data_range', {id: key}))
   );
}
```

.env settings

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

web.php

```
Route::post('report/data_range','AnalyticsApp\ReportController@ChartDataGet');
```

ReportController.php

```
public function ChartDataGet(Request $request)
    {
        return Chart::find($request->id)
    }
```

Requests' timing

[image: requests]

Answer (score -1):

Your first call axios use **await**, this specifies that you wait for it to finish. You can remove this **await** but it seems that it is necessary for the **data_range**. If it not required, you can remove.

Comment: But even I remove "await", all requests weren't handle concurrently

Comment: This solution resolve convert the call chart_data to parallel. Then it depends on the server configuration as these calls are answered